# Add sidebar to the right of webpage that resizes and shifts everything accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, sidebar

I'm creating an Chrome Extension, which should add sidebar to all webpages.
This sidebar shouldn't overlap webpage content, it should be placed next to the existing content, essentially shrinking width of body of webpage to `initial width - sidebar width`.

This is the code I came up with, but I have a problem with some pages like stackoverflow for instance, see how top bar doesn't shrink like the rest of the page does (screenshots attached below the code)

```
        // create sidebar
        const sidebar = document.createElement("iframe");
        sidebar.src = chrome.extension.getURL("iframe/iframe.html");
        sidebar.id = "extensionSidebar";
        sidebar.frameBorder = "0";
        sidebar.style.height = "100%";
        sidebar.style.width = "100px";
        sidebar.style.position = "fixed";
        sidebar.style.top = "0";
        sidebar.style.right = "0";
        sidebar.style.zIndex = "2147483646";

        // append sidebar to body
        document.documentElement.appendChild(sidebar);

        // shrink body
        document.body.style.width = window.innerWidth - 100 + "px";
```

Screenshots:

https://prnt.sc/o215x5

https://prnt.sc/o21637

Comment: This question was asked several times on StackOverflow, and I think there are several potentially useful answers, so try searching (in google). There's no universal solution, though. You'll have to apply CSS hacks and exclusions on a per-site basis.

Answer (score 1):

The top bar doesn't shrink as you would like it to do because it is fixed, it will always take 100% of the viewport width. Its CSS properties on your example with stackoverflow are :

```
...
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%; /*though it's not "really" 100vw*/
...
```

Even by changing the `html` element in CSS, in order to change its maximum size to 80% of the viewport width for instance, the navbar would still take all the viewport's width.

To understand it you can try the following fiddle, it might speak for istelf : https://jsfiddle.net/bcg2vkjm/4/

On it you can "un-comment" the body element inside the CSS and see the result, it might give you some help ! Though it only applies a scale of 1 (so it should not change...), for some reason it makes the fixed element adapt to the body size, which is what you want, you just might have to play along with the `translateX` and/or `scale` in the CSS, but it might be a risky solution because it changes quite a lot the way everything is displayed, not only the fixed element, as you can see.

In your javascript you can try the following :

> document.querySelector('body').style.transform = "scaleX(something)";

for instance !